# How to translate from jquery to pure javascript this finsweet hack #4 for webflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, translate, webflow

I got a code in Jquery and need it in pure javascript. Could you help me to translate this same code in pure javascript ?
I've let the comments to make it easier.

ORIGINAL JQUERY CODE:

```
     // when DOM's ready
$(document).ready(function() {
       const linkTextArr = []; 
    // for each filter button
       $('.navlink_button').each((index, link) => {
    // get its text content and reformat to a valid ID
       let linkText = $(link).text().replace(/\W/g,'_').toLowerCase(); 
    // set the reformatted linkText as the link href attribute
       $(link).attr('href', '#'+linkText);
    // push reformatted linkText to array 
       linkTextArr.push(linkText);
       });
    // for each section
       $('.hack4-cms-anchor-section').each((index, section) => {     

       $(section).attr('id', linkTextArr[index]);
       });
    // set up intrsection observer 
       let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => { 
    // for each anchor section
       entries.forEach(entry => {
    // if it's in the viewport
       if(entry.isIntersecting){
       $('.navlink_button.hack4-active').removeClass('hack4-active');
       $(`.navlink_button[href='#${entry.target.id}']`).addClass('hack4-active');
       }
       });
    // set thrshld to 1 ensures the whole anchor section
    // is in viewport before adding active class to active link
       }, {threshold: 0});
    // start intersection observer for each anchor section
       $('.hack4-cms-anchor-section').each((i,sec) => observer.observe(sec) );
       });
```

I tried to translate it like this, by replacing all the selectors:

```
// when DOM's ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// create empty array that will store link text strings 
   const linkTextArr = []; 
// for each filter button
   document.querySelectorAll('.navlink_button').each((index, link) => {
// get its text content and reformat to a valid ID
   let linkText = document.querySelector(link).text().replace(/\W/g,'_').toLowerCase(); 
    // set the reformatted linkText as the link href attribute
  document.querySelector(link).attr('href', '#'+linkText);
// push reformatted linkText to array 
   linkTextArr.push(linkText);
// console.log(linkText);
   });

// for each section
// ex: hellosign > hellosign 
document.querySelectorAll('.hack4-cms-anchor-section').each((index, section) => {     
// set id attribute to linkTextArray value sequentially
// 1st section gets id: linkTextArr[0]
// 2nd section gets id: linkTextArr[1] and so on
   document.querySelectorAll(section).attr('id', linkTextArr[index]);
   });
// set up intrsctn obsrvr 
// (navlnk btn highlight when on sectn)
// 2 observ whn th anchor sectns ar in viewport
   let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => { 
// for each anchor section
   entries.forEach(entry => {
// if it's in the viewport
   if(entry.isIntersecting){
// remov l'active class from current active link
document.querySelector('.navlink_button.hack4-active').removeClass('hack4-active');
// add the active class to the current active link
document.querySelector(`.navlink_button[href='#${entry.target.id}']`).addClass('hack4-active');
       }
       });
    // set thrshld to 1 ensures the whole anchor section
    // is in viewport before adding active class to active link
    // this part ', {threshold: 1}' is optional
       }, {threshold: 0});
    // start intersection observer for each anchor section
    document.querySelectorAll('.hack4-cms-anchor-section').each((i,sec) => observer.observe(sec) );
       });
```

But I don't know how to translate this line with this #${ :

```
$(`.navlink_button[href='#${entry.target.id}']`).addClass('hack4-active');
```

after that can you tell me if there something else that is still jQuery on my translation ?

Comment: Take a look at [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) it shows pure/vanilla alternatives to jQuery methods

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, this might help you but you have to unit test your code because you can't entirely depend on some online tool in case of conversion logics.

[Convert Jquery code to vanila Javascript](https://properprogramming.com/tools/jquery-to-javascript-converter/)

Here, I have done activity for you. Please test it and replace the selectors if you find some error or glitch in it.

```
 document.querySelector(document).ready(function() {
   const linkTextArr = []; 
// for each filter button
   document.querySelector('.navlink_button').each((index, link) => {
// get its text content and reformat to a valid ID
   let linkText = document.querySelector(link).text().replace(/W/g,'_').toLowerCase(); 
// set the reformatted linkText as the link href attribute
   document.querySelector(link).attr('href', '#'+linkText);
// push reformatted linkText to array 
   linkTextArr.push(linkText);
   });
// for each section
   document.querySelector('.hack4-cms-anchor-section').each((index, section) => {     

   document.querySelector(section).attr('id', linkTextArr[index]);
   });
// set up intrsection observer 
   let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => { 
// for each anchor section
   entries.forEach(entry => {
// if it's in the viewport
   if(entry.isIntersecting){
   document.querySelector('.navlink_button.hack4-active').removeClass('hack4-active');
   document.querySelector(`.navlink_button[href='#${entry.target.id}']`).classList.add('hack4-active');
   }
   });
// set thrshld to 1 ensures the whole anchor section
// is in viewport before adding active class to active link
   }, {threshold: 0});
// start intersection observer for each anchor section
   document.querySelector('.hack4-cms-anchor-section').each((i,sec) => observer.observe(sec) );
   });
```